# Trying to make one method. Put message method inside new method in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

Below are two method which work in conjunction to output and error message. I want to find a way to have the same functionality but reduce it to one method.

```
# Method for creating error message
  sub new {
      my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;
      # Initialize error with data
      my $self = $error;
      # If the error contains context parameters... Insert parameters into string template
      foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
          
          # And take the ones we need
          $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
      }
      return bless $self, $class;
  }

    # Method which inserts variables into template hash field from the error hash structure
 

  sub message {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return sprintf $self->template,
                 map { $self->args->{$_} } @{ $self->context };
  }
```

Here is Type.pm ; where my error hash structures are located.

```
 UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR => {
         category => 'Connection Error',
         template => "Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.",
         context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
         tt => {template => 'disabled'},
         fatal => 1,
         wiki_page => 'www.error-fix-link.com/',
     },
```

Each field in the error hash contains a getter.

Any help would be much appreciated. If more information is needed just comment below. Thanks

## Update:

This is the way I was trying to go, but I am getting an error saying I can use method 'template' on an unblessed reference. What I want to do is make message an element/attribute of the object created by the new() method. If that makes sense?

```
# Method for creating error message
  sub new {
      my ( $class, $error, %args ) = @_;
      # Initialize error with data
      my $self = $error;
      # If the error contains context parameters... Insert parameters into string template
      if(%args) {
          foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
              # And take the ones we need
              $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
              # map/insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
              $self->template, map{ $self->{args}->{$key} } @{ $self->context };

          }
          # message var maps the parameters the message string (template)
          return bless $self, $class;
      }
      return bless $self, $class;
  }
```

Comment: You can't have the same functionality since one method returns an object and one returns a string. I assume you mean that you want `new` to return an object with an attribute set to that string, correct? In which case you can just move the logic from `message` into `new`.

Comment: `$self->template` means call the `template` method on object `$self`. `$self` is not an object and I see no `template` function anywhere. What exactly are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: I think you want something like `$self->{message} = sprintf $self->{template}, map ...`

Comment: Also, the first `return` is redundant, you can get rid of it.

Comment: Aw yeah, I understand that. Okay thanks. :)

Comment: Your question has morphed into a totally different question, so you should make a new post. Good rule of thumb: if somebody has invested time writing an answer, don't edit your question to the point that the answer no longer addresses the question. Posting lots of questions is fine, as long as they're actually different questions.

Comment: Also, "Use of uninitialized value in sprintf" is not the same error you had before.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error

> Can't call method "foo" on unblessed reference

when you try to call a method on something that's not an object. For example:

```
my $h = {}; # hashref, not an object
$h->foo;
```

---

The line

```
$self->template, map{ $self->{args}->{$key} } @{ $self->context };
```

tries to call the method `template` on the object `$self`, but

- `$self` is not an object (it's a hash reference)
- `template` is not a method (it's a hash key)
- you don't assign the result to anything

You have the same issue with `$self->context`, which tries to call the non-existent method `context` on `$self`.

To populate your template and assign it to an attribute of your object, do:

```
my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };
$self->{message} = sprintf( $self->{template}, @template_args );
```

You should do this outside of the `foreach` loop because you only need to evaluate the template once.

Comment: Yeah I had it outside the for loop. I'm still getting the same error though . hmmm....

Comment: See my latest edit. You forgot the curly braces in `$self->context`. Remember, `$object->foo` (no curlies) calls method `foo`, while `$hashref->{foo}` (with curlies) accesses key `foo` in a hash reference.